# A parallelogram with sides $8$ and $6$ and angle of $30^\circ$ between them is rotated around its larger side

Tags: solid-of-revolution, platonic-solids

A parallelogram with sides $8$ and $6$ and angle of $30^\circ$ between them is rotated around its larger side. Find the volume of the formed solid.

I really can't imagine what we'll get. This is what I was able to draw as a diagram, but I really can't imagine it in my head.

[image]

We can find the height $DH$ of the parallelogram which is $DH=\dfrac12AD=3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as the volume of the cylinder (pull the cone off from one side and push it into the other side). So:
$$8\cdot\pi3^2.$$

Comment: Thank you, but I really have issues visualizing it in my head. Are we actually sure that the radius of the cylinder is the same as the height of the parallelogram through $D$, and why?

Comment: Both are the same as the height of the parallelogram through $C.$

Comment: This is not a proof...

Comment: This [proof without words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) seems sufficient. Adding formal arguments would obsure the obviousness. Btw, @yinivem462 thank you for the picture, it is very helpful.